# Is there a correspondence between the linear representation of a compact group and the linear representation of the algebra generated by the group?

Tags: representation-theory

I know that such correspondence exists when the group is finite. I'm trying to take the basic linear representation theory of finite groups to compact groups. Specifically I'm trying to see if the concept of F[G]-module is well defined.

Comment: The concept of $F[G]$-module is well-defined… except that it really doesn’t use the topology of $G$. It really is the same thing as an abstract representation of $G$ over $F$, without any condition of continuity or finite dimension (so no hope of using compactness). This is why we usually need to impose further conditions which often aren’t as straightforward to write down – for instance, continuity (for complex representations of a Lie group, or $p$-adic representations of a profinite group), or smoothness (for any $F,G$ but more restrictive – points must have open stabilizers).

Comment: Yeah, I need the condition that the representation are continuous functions (for compact groups). I want to make sure that if we extend a continuous linear representation of $G$ to $F[G]$ then that extension is also continuous. (I do not know if extend is the right word in english). @Aphelli